# WordPress: How Do I Show x Amount of Posts Latest Posts on Landing Page - Matching the Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, css-grid

On my website, I want a landing/homepage and a blog page. I went to Settings > Reading > Your Homepage displays "static page" and chose my homepage & blogs page.

My theme uses a grid layout for the posts. On my homepage, I want to show 6 posts and then a "more posts" link to the rest of the posts on /blog.

I want the homepage to display the posts like my theme was set to. Any widget or plugin I use does not display the posts like my theme does, so I was thinking of editing the

`<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>` code to only show the latest 6 posts. and add it to the "homepage" page. Is this possible?

Below is a picture of how my theme displays posts.

[image: gird post layout]

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need to set the main WP_Query at frontpage to have the "post_per_page" parameter set to 6. You may use the [pre_get_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) hook to alter the main query. WP_Query provides an [is_front_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_front_page/) method for you to check if the query is of the front page.

In your theme's [functions.php](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/), add these lines:

```php
add_action('pre_get_posts','alter_query');
function alter_query(WP_Query $query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_front_page()) {
        // Only alter the frontpage main query
        $query->set('post_per_page', 6);
    }
}
```

The [have_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/have_posts/), [the_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post/) functions all works with the main WP_Query object. Hence all should be working according to the new query setup.